# How to nest macro definitions in M4?

Tags: macros, m4

I would like to define a macro that can define more macros as:

```
define(`master_macro',
`foreachq(`slave_macro', `$*',
define(`slave_macro', ...)'
```

then I can use `master_macro` to define more similar `slave_macro`s as:

```
master_macro(m1, m2, m3, ...)
```

The reason why I need this is that the number and names of `slave_macro` are unknown when I write M4 macros.

Comment: Or is there any macro processor that allows programmable macro definitions? I saw Ruby's potential for such feature, but need I write one?

Comment: I have implemented a trial macro processor in Ruby that can do this task.

Comment: Have you defined `foreachq`?  The example given in the gnu m4 documentation is not describing an m4 builtin; `foreachq` is a sample macro whose definition is provided in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for can certainly be done.  Here's an example:

```
$ cat file
changequote(`[',`]')dnl
define([factory],[dnl
define($1,banana)dnl
define($2,split)dnl
])dnl
factory(hello,world)dnl
hello world
$ m4 file
banana split
```

I think the problem is your usage of the undefined macro `foreachq`.